# Ansible Custom Module - Best way to define variables?

Tags: module, parameters, ansible, api-key

I wrote a custom module for ansible that call REST API, and I pass the parameters (base_url and api_key) with parameters defined in the playbook.
That's fine, but I would like to store somewhere these two parameters so that they have not to be defined in the playbook.
Is there an official way to do that ?

Thanks for your answers, but I need to be more clear with an example.
Here is a task

```
tasks:
  - name: Check if all files are present
    Full_case1:
      param1: 'xxxxx'
      param2: 'xxxxxxxx'
      base_url: '{{ my base url }}'
      api_key: '{{ my api key }}'
```

I would like to suppress base_url and api_key from the params to call the module.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: you can store them in some yaml file and `import_vars` that yaml

Comment: There are [many places where you can write your values letting users override them or not](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence). Just pick the right one for your use case